# UWP with Prism - handling more than one instance of UserControl on a Page

Tags: user-controls, uwp, prism

We're using Prism with UWP, and have a UserControl which we want to display several times in a Grid (each instance relating to a connected user).

If the UserControl were a Page, I know of course that the code can/should go in associated ViewModel. What's the equivalent for the UserControl? I obviously want to keep my code DRY, and call the same code for each UserControl instance.

My research is pointing me towards a Dependency Property, but I haven't found a clear example of how I should implement it.

**Note** that the UserControl needs to display data and *also* implement Buttons with associated Commands on the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Create a separate view model

You could create a view model specifically for the user control. The DataContext of the user control would be set to an instance of this view model. You can expose commands and data related to each user in the view model and bind to them in the user control, just like you would if it were a page.

This scenario works best if the user control can function independently of the page it is in. If you need the user control VM to communicate to the page VM, then you'll need to facilitate this somehow between the VMs (maybe the user control VM can take a reference to the page VM as a dependency upon construction).

### Expose command properties in the user control

Another way is to create dependency properties for each command you want to expose in the user control, which can then be bound to in the page's XAML.

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Delete" Command="{x:Bind DeleteCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

```
public sealed partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public ICommand DeleteCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(DeleteCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DeleteCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DeleteCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DeleteCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Now you can bind to `DeleteCommand` on the user control.

---

Typically I use some combination of both of these methods when I use user controls.

Comment: Thanks,that's useful. With the ViewModel approach, I'm using prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel in my XAML for my Pages.

Can I use AutoWireViewModel with UserControls too? Or am I better creating the ViewModel and setting it as the DataContext/Binding in the UserControl's xaml.cs code behind?

Comment: In this scenario you probably wouldn't auto wire the VM. The page VM would be responsible for creating and managing each user control VM, that way you have complete control over the VMs and any data they might require (such as the page VM instance, for example). Any dependencies the user control VM requires would have to be injected into the page VM and passed to the constructor of each user control VM.

Comment: If the page VM creates the user control VMs, where do we bind the user control to its VM? I was thinking instead along the lines (as you suggested earlier) of the control VM getting the Page VM via dependency injection, and 'registering' itself with the Page VM so that the Page VM (via a public method I write for the Page VM).

Comment: You expose the user control VMs in a property (perhaps an ObservableCollection) on your page VM and bind the GridView's ItemsSource to that collection. The DataContext of each GridViewItem will be a VM.